# Import/Export functionality for rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, activerecord, export

I would like to give my users the ability of export and import their posts on my server, including images, comments and whatever linked data to the object.

Basically I would like them to be able to click somewhere and receive a zip file, if they open it they will see several xml, or json, or yaml files and the image files that were part of their posts.

They can then upload the files and have back their posts in the way they were when they exported.

I couldn't find any tutorial, or gem to help me in this, would you be able to recommend me the design to approach this issue?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I did it this way for exports:

- Create a new temporary directory
- Serialize everything you want exported to your format of choice and write it into a file in that directory
- make sure the images are clearly identifiable, e.g. by serializing their file names instead of arcane IDs
- copy the image files in the temporary directory
- zip the whole dir (can be done via system commands)
- optionally, but it's a good idea: move the whole shebang into a background job and notify the user once their file is ready for download.

I'm not sure if import is feasible this way, or even a good idea, but you can try.

One neat trick to specify which fields/attributes are exported is to overwrite `Record#attribute_names`.

Say you want to export only title, body and creation date of a Post object that usually also has updated_at, user_id, etc.

```
# in the export script you'd write
class Post
  def attribute_names
    ['title', 'body', 'created_at']
  end
end

Post.export_for(@user).all.to_yaml
```

It's important to only do this in the export script, because you screw with record introspection here. Usually, though, the export methods (to_yaml, to_xml, etc) rely on this mechanism to determine what to export, so doing this locally/temporarily works great.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it's probably not a good idea to load user uploaded data in the database. The security measures to be implemented with such approach would be really massive.